# Insert a document only if certain properties do not match any current documents (via an upsert?)

Tags: mongodb

Is there a method for inserting a new document which does not contain certain properties in MongoDB?

For example, say I want to insert a document which looks like:

```
{
    'f_name': 'Jim',
    'l_name': 'Jones',
    'age': 21,
    'country': 'UK',
    ...etc...
}
```

But I wanted to insert this document *only if* a document containing

```
{
    'f_name': 'Jim',
    'l_name': 'Jones'
}
```

did not already exist.  Is there a way of doing this in a single operation (e.g. like an upsert, but without modifying any existing matching documents if one exists), or does this have to be done in two seperate operations (a lookup to see if one exists, then an insert)?

It's not majorly important, but it would be quite useful to know about and could save a lot of time!

Comment: One option is to use a compound unique index here on f_name and l_name

Comment: Yeah, that'd work, although it would limit to to only checking the compound unique indexes (rather than any properties).

Comment: The alternative is to do two queries or use an upsert `db.update({f_name:jim,l_name:jones}, {//doc}, {upsert:true})`

Comment: If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use one of two options:

- A compound unique index
- An upsert like so:

  db.col.update({f_name: 'Jim', l_name: 'Jones'}, {//your doc here}, {upsert: true})

This will basically search for a document where these fields already have these values and updates (you can just update the fields with their same value) or inserts if the find criteria does not return results.

A last ditch try it is to use two queries, however the upsert above should work quite nicely.

Comment: Of these options I would recommend using an index. When you don't have an index on these two fields, the runtime of the update query above is linear to the number of entries in the collection.

Comment: @Philipp: I will have various indexes on the collection which will correspond to the various fields being queried, so that shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: @Shri dunno I ain't programmed Java in a long time